# Yes/No :Is $(x,y)$ is inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra

let $x= ( x_1, x_2,......, x_n)$  an $y= ( y_1, y_2,...,y_n)$  be arbitary vectors in $V_n$. Determine whether $\langle x,y\rangle$ is an inner product for $V_n$ where $\langle x,y\rangle $ is given by

$\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i +y_i)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{n }y_i^2$

My attempt : I thinks it will not  form inner product

take $a^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 $  and $b^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n }y_i^2$

Now  $\langle x, y\rangle=  a^2+ b^2 + 2ab - a^2 -b^2= 2ab=2\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i  \sum_{i=1}^{n }y_i$

Now take $x= ( 1,-1,0,0,.....)$ and $y= (-1,1,0,0,.....)$

so $\langle x, y\rangle =0 $ but $ x \neq 0 , y \neq 0$

Its contradicts the axioms of inner product space

therefore $\langle x,y\rangle$ is not inner product space

Is its true ?

Comment: Which axiom of an inner product space do you think is being contradicted exactly?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen positivity

Comment: I think perhaps you're a bit confused about the axioms `:)`. This isn't the only problem with your reasoning, but it's worth going over. Usually the requirement for an inner product is that $\langle x, x \rangle > 0$ for $x \ne 0$. This doesn't tell you anything about $\langle x, y \rangle$ if they are different. Indeed, the dot product on $\mathbb R^n$ can be zero or negative for distinct vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Your mistake comes from the equality
$$a=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$$
which is false.

$$\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n\Bigl((x_i+y_i)^2-x_i^2-y_i^2\Bigr)$$
$$=2\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i$$
It is clearly an inner product since $ \sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i $ is the well known Euclidian product.